# ffmpeg : "Error setting profile"; how to keep original resolution odf odd sized videos; getting Quicktime compatible output; fixing pixel format

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been having trouble using ffmpeg to compress videos to something readable by quicktime.  My goal in the end is to have a simple command that I can use to compress high bitrate videos (ie screencaptures) to something more reasonable to be able to share them with people.

I want to use a command I found [here](https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/) as a starting point:

```
ffmpeg -i input-file.avi -codec:v libx264 -profile: high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output_file.mp4
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7f92ab81c200] Error setting profile high.
[libx264 @ 0x7f92ab81c200] Possible profiles: baseline main high high10 high422 high444
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

If I take out the `-profile: high` the command functions but the output still doesn't open in quicktime (it does in VLC).  I can't find the keyword `-profile` on the ffmpeg man page: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html so I don't know if this is important or what to do about it.

Does anyone know what might be causing my problem? What should I do to try and debug this problem? I would describe myself as inexperienced so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Peter

This is my ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
```

Comment: Questions about interactive use of the ffmpeg command line tool are off-topic. Please ask them on the Super User - https://superuser.com/ or Video Production - https://video.stackexchange.com/ sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably an issue of the pixel format. Try

```
ffmpeg -i input-file.avi -vf scale=-2:480,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output_file.mp4
```

I've added a conversion to YUV420P. This can also be specified as a separate option via `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: I would now like to make the command as generic as possible, in particular I would like to avoid changing the resolution (as in height and width) of the video.  Deleting `-vf scale=-2:480,format=yuv420p` and replacing with `-pix_fmt yuv420p` gave `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'yuv420p'`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the command so I won't post it.  The corrected command was : `ffmpeg -i input-file.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output_file.mp4` and the first error was `[libx264 @ 0x7ff584007e00] width not divisible by 2 (669x529)`. (The video is an odd sized screen capture)

Comment: Add `-vf scale=iw:-2`

Comment: @P.Reid There is no reason to set the profile to high. Anything that can decode high profile can decode main and baseline as well, and the encoder will use high if it can. You only need to use `-profile:v` if you want to set the profile to main or baseline, depending on which devices, browsers, players, etc you are willing to support. You also don't need `-threads 0`, which means "auto choose appropriate number of threads" which is the default anyway. Lastly, `-maxrate` and `-bufsize` are usually for streaming, so you don't need those for something that will just play locally.

Comment: When I run this: `ffmpeg -i input-file.avi -vf scale=iw:-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v 400k -maxrate 400k -bufsize 800k -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output_file.mp4` I get this still: `[libx264 @ 0x7f875181c200] width not divisible by 2 (669x530)`.  Thanks for your help

Comment: `-vf scale=2*trunc(iw/2):-2`

Comment: Oh sorry, the command line was `ffmpeg -i input-file.avi -vf scale=2*trunc(iw/2):-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v 400k -maxrate 400k -bufsize 800k -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output_file.mp4` I think I see what you're doing there (adding a line if necessary to make the line number even)

Comment: Enclose 2*trunc(iw/2) in ' '

Comment: I've got everything I wanted.  Thanks so much.  Here is the final incantation.  `ffmpeg -i input-file.avi -vf scale='2*trunc(iw/2)':-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -b:v 400k -maxrate 400k -bufsize 800k -threads 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output_file.mp4`

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard for your helpful explanations.  I intend to put the files on my owncloud for people to watch via the web interface.  Can you confirm that -profile main; -maxrate;  and -bufsize; are worth specifying for this use case?

Comment: @P.Reid If you want to ensure compatibility with old devices, such as iPhone 4 and older, you can keep `-profile:v main`. If they are viewing the video via a web site (progressive download) then add `-movflags +faststart`. Personally, I would just be lazy and use `-crf` instead of `-b:v -maxrate -bufsize`, but I don't know anything about your content, clients, network, system, restrictions, goals, etc.