# Flutter FFMPEG: Error setting profile baseline

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

[Flutter-ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) unable to set profile parameter. (I need to use profile so the rendered video can be played on WhatsApp).

I am converting.bmp images into a mp4 video. Other I have tested other praramets and the work great it's only -profile:v which seems to have some problem.

Everything works fine unless I use `-profile:v baseline`.

```
void _runFFmpeg() async {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String videoSize = '${ImageWidth}x$ImageSize';
    print("${ImageWidth}x$ImageSize");
    var arguments = [
      "-y", // replace output file if it already exists
      "-framerate", "30", // framrate
      "-video_size", videoSize,
      "-pixel_format", "yuv420p",
      "-i", "${output.path}/frame_%d.bmp",  
      "-profile:v", "baseline",
      "-level", "3.0",
      "${output.path}/test.mp4"
    ];
    
    _flutterFFmpeg
        .executeWithArguments(arguments)
        .then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
 

    print("Done Rendering");
  }
```

**Logs**

```
D/flutter-ffmpeg(26672): Running FFmpeg with arguments: [-y, -framerate, 30, -video_size, 720x600, -pixel_format, yuv420p, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files/frame_%d.bmp, -profile:v, baseline, -level, 3.0, /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files/test.mp4].
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files/frame_%d.bmp':
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   Duration:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): 00:00:06.03
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): , start:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): 0.000000
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): , bitrate:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): N/A
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):     Stream #0:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): : Video: bmp, yuv420p, 720x600
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): ,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): 30 fps,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): 30 tbr,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): 30 tbn,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): 30 tbc
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): Stream mapping:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):  (bmp (native) -> h264 (libx264))
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
W/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7280948480] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
E/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100] Error setting profile baseline.
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100] Possible profiles:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]  baseline
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]  main
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]  high
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]  high10
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]  high422
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]  high444
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): [libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100]
E/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
I/mobile-ffmpeg(26672): Conversion failed!
D/flutter-ffmpeg(26672): FFmpeg exited with rc: 1
E/UIFirst (26672): failed to open /proc/26672/stuck_info, No such file or directory
I/chatty  (26672): uid=12724(com.example.test) identical 2 lines
3
E/UIFirst (26672): failed to open /proc/26672/stuck_info, No such file or directory
I/chatty  (26672): uid=12724(com.example.test) identical 1 line
E/UIFirst (26672): failed to open /proc/26672/stuck_info, No such file or directory
```

**Flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at C:\Users\Dell\flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (5 weeks ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0
[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • RMX1801 (mobile) • 8843cc23 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114
• No issues found!
```

I also have tried changing package to min-gpl, https-gpl and video but no change.

Comment: I am having a similar issue but maybe with the formatting, can you please take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045090/flutter-ffmpeg-error-option-not-found-when-using-filter)?

Answer (score 0):

I am only familiar with FFmpeg, not with the plugin for Flutter so I can't test easily.

But I suspect you use scaling as an input option.

To apply the scaling to the output, move `"-i", "${output.path}/frame_%d.bmp",` right after `-y`.

If your log still displays `[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7280948480] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored`, use a different option for scaling:

Instead of `"-video_size", videoSize,`I would use `"-vf", "scale=720:600",`.

If this doesn't help try to substitute `-profile:v` for either `-vprofile` or `-profile`.

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborated answer. I tried everything you suggest but no change in error. But I might got a useful result. When I used only '-profile' the log said to use '-profile:a" or '-profile:v' . Since '-profile:v' is not working I used '-profile:a' and I did got output without any error but problem is the same that is without the profile parameter. I get a video, it runs on my phone but when sharing the video on Social Media a grey screen comes. So, '-profile:v' gives an error, and  'profile:a' didn't give an error but it didn't make the video playable on WhatsApp. Any idea why?

Comment: You're welcome! So the problem is `[libx264 @ 0x7291ba8100] Error setting profile baseline.`which is odd because `baseline` is a valid option. But this can happen due to a wrong pixel format like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42471886/6444590). But your pixel format seems to be correct. Test your code with 1) different profiles `main` and `high`. 2) different source image formats like `PNG` and `JPG`. 3) Did the `scale=` option get rid of the `sws_param option is deprecated and ignored`?

Comment: I have used all profile options none worked. And no scale= option didn't help with sws_param. Got the same error. I tried other ways than a profile to make the video compatible with WhatsApp but non worked. What I also did is first render video without a profile and then used the profile option for the rendered video, it didn't game any error but video still didn't worked on whatsapp. I think 'sws_param option is deprecated and ignored is the real problem. But again I didn't know much about ffmpeg.

Comment: According to [this](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-September/002300.html), `video_size` is "a string describing frame size (instead of -s before -i)". So this seems to be the wrong option. Please give it another try with `"-s", "720x600",`.